# Dropdown list on textbox (autocomplete) disappear when no result

Tags: jquery, ajax, autocomplete

My javascript code autocomplete call ajax to get result(json) from test2.php(query data)
It's work if have result and if result is null autocomplete should disappear but don't disappear
I try to get some bug or error, press F12 on browser in console appear "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null"

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#name1').autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            var name = $('#name1').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'test2.php',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    p : name
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    response($.map(data, function(item) {
                        return {
                            value : item.name
                        };
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 1,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).val(ui.item.value);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Please help I'm newbie jquery ajax

Comment: Does the error say which line of which .js file?

Comment: m.extend.map @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2
j @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2
k.fireWith @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2
x @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5
b @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5

2 and 5
in my file response(... line

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps if a empty result is returned. Any actin on Null value will throw error. So added "if(data){do some thing...}" so you can apply your logic there.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#name1').autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        var name = $('#name1').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'test2.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                p : name
            },
            success: function(data) {
                if(data){
                 response($.map(data, function(item) {
                    return {
                        value : item.name
                    };
                }));
            }else{alert("No result so do some thing")}
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 1,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        var test = ui.item ? ui.item.id : 0;
         if (test > 0)
         {
          $(this).val(ui.item.value);
         }            
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: can detect null value, but how to disappear dropdown autocomplete

Comment: Modified my answer. hope this is what you are looking for

Comment: No sorry. I mean, dropdown list on textbox disappear when no result

Answer (score 0):

I use .autocomplete('close') to solve my problem. Thanks every answer and comment ;)

```
success: function(data) {
                    if(jQuery.isEmptyObject(data)){
                        $('#name1').autocomplete( "close" );
                    }else {
                        response($.map(data, function(item) {
                            return {
                                value : item.name
                            };
                        }));
                    }
                }
```